# Rolling logged in timeout with Azure b2c and Blazor

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM that is secure with Azure B2C with Custom policy. Everything works well but I am struggling to figure out how to implement a standard behavior of the app timing out in a predefined time unless there is activity going on in the app.

First I tried adding expiration to my custom policy

```
<SingleSignOn Scope="Application" />
<SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType>
<SessionExpiryInSeconds>900</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
```

That works as in after 900 seconds if I refresh the app it'll ask to re-login but unless I refresh the app I can continue using it indefinitely. After some more research I now understand (I think) that only page refresh is performs reauthentication and therefore extends the session expiration.

My next thought would be to user `exp` claim from the JWT token and make my own logic to check and extend it on route changes and maybe API calls. But it doesn't seem that claims can be updated after an authentication (which I feel is like that because that would be a security weak link).

Is the only option really keeping the expiration timeout state entirely outside of any azure b2c and Identity Model, just like any other states I maintain through my application.

I feel like both the desired behavior and azure b2c is common enough that there must be some standard technique or best practice - asking for a sanity check here before I go overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your query on Q&A. We don't have any best practices for Azure B2C session control as session control practice is defined by the organization objective. However we have a few [Recommendations and best practices for Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/best-practices#testing) which may help you in evaluating the deployment as a whole.

Thanks

Comment: So how would I extend the session as my user is active around the app if I can't modify the token after it was issued and `<SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType>` is only updated when there is an authentication action?

Comment: @americanslon                                                                                           
When "SessionExpiryType" set to "Rolling" Indicates that the session is extended every time the user performs a cookie-based authentication (default) "SessionExpiryInSeconds" is The amount of time the Azure AD B2C session cookie is stored on the user's browser after successful authentication. You can set the session lifetime up to 24 hours. If you don't want the user to reauthenticate after browser refresh then try enabling KMSI.

Comment: Kindly follow [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-the-metadata-to-the-self-asserted-technical-profile) to enable KMSI, please be informed that this works for OpenID and local accounts only. This would not work for federated IDP as B2C could not control 3rd party IDP session.

Comment: The issue here is that the user never performs cookie-based authentication after the original authentication, why would they? They are just doing their work within the app. So the authentication never "rolls". If `SessionExpiryType` is set to 20 minutes the user can authenticate, be actively using the app (moving around the app etc.) and the session would still expire after 20 minutes.

Comment: any thoughts on what I said above?